# How to keep history of changes in a very simple table in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple grid in my view (ASP.NET MVC, using C#) where I add data about people and their salaries. My database has only on table, so it is pretty straightforward. What I need is to keep track when someone makes changes in the table values.

I need to keep track of the name of the user who made the change, the column where he made the change and the date... (It would be great to keep track of the changed value, but it is optional for now)

There are some solution in stack overflow but they are too complicated, I just need a simple solution for one table only.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you use an auditing structure this is quite easy. Simply add an `EndEffectiveTimestamp` equivalent column and then only insert records and update the old record's `EndEffectiveTimestamp` to the current date. Only show records where that timestamp is null. You will have a full audit trail if you do something similar to this.

Comment: The simplest solution would be a trigger that writes to an 'audit' table, have a look at [Audit Trail Generator for Microsoft SQL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21068/Audit-Trail-Generator-for-Microsoft-SQL)

Answer (score 2):

There are a various different approaches to this. The most sophisticated and flexible would be a full blown [event sourcing](http://cqrs.nu/Faq/event-sourcing) solution... but I get the feeling that might be overkill in your situation.

Another option, that springs to mind (not the most compact, but probably the simplest to implement) would be to keep a second table which is identical to the original table, only without any unique indexes or constraints or anything and with the addition of a couple of extra columns (changeDate, changedBy - and optionally a changeType).

So if your original table is called people and the change tracking table is people_log, whenever you make a CRUD operation on the people table you also insert an appropriate corresponding record in the people_log table. The very first entry that would go in people_log would be when a person gets inserted and the record in the people_log table would, at that point, contain a copy of all the original values for the person, along with the changeDate, who changed the record (e.g. 'bob') and a changeType = 'insert'. As time goes by there will be various updates and perhaps eventually even a delete...

The disadvantage of this approach is that you're storing a duplication of every field in a people record even when only a single field is changed. If you don't have too many columns or if you have less than a couple of million people in your table, this probably isn't going to be a huge issue, to be honest... so I'd probably role with this solution simply on the basis of ease of implementation. There are, of course, alternative less disk hungry approaches you could take.

Comment: I like your idea. . I there any sample solution online where I can look at ?

Answer (score 2):

I created something similar to this..

If I remember correctly I created a table and named it `Update_History`

```
ID - primary key for your audit table
RecordID - primary key of the record edited
ColumnName - name of column with value edited
Previous_Value - value before edit
New_Value - value after edit
Date_Created - date when update was made
Created_By - user who made the update
```

Previous_Value = refer to the object you used to display the values before being updated; for example a `GridView`.

New_Value = refer to the object you used for the user input to be saved; for example a `DropDownList` or a `TextBox`.

You can then get the history by linking to `RecordID` with the primary key of your table.

Comment: How to get this values:
Previous_Value - value before edit
New_Value - value after edit

Comment: Before your `UPDATE` statement to your `Salary` table, `INSERT` the values first on audit table.